# Inserting multiple lines into a border in CSS?

Tags: html, css, styling

I have a page where I want the border to home more than one line.

```
h2.bord
{
border-style:inset;
border-width:8px;
border-color:green;
background-color:black;
color:white;
text-align:center;
}
```

This (when used) displays a border around the text.
However,
I want to home more than I one line in this border.

Help?

Comment: Why is this question have [php] tag on it?

Comment: check this http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-multiple-borders-with-simple-css/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a div with border and inside that place this h2 bord

Answer (score 1):

Is `border-style:double;` what you are looking for?

Alternatively, if you wanted more than a double border's, or borders of multiple styles you could use multiple nested divs, e.g.

```
<style>
  .inset-border { border: 4px inset Black; }
  .double-border { border: 4px double Black; }
</style>

<div class="inset-border">
  <div class="double-border">
    <h2>content</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. I want to be able to insert more than one line of text into the border.

Comment: You can't insert text into a border. A border is a decorative edge around the containing element.

Answer (score 0):

Standard CSS borders only support at the very most a double line (see @Jaimal's answer).

If you need more than that, you need to try the following:

- Additional markup: ie more container elements, each with their own border.
- Use `:before` and `:after` and give them a `border`. Done right, they should wrap around the original box and give you extra borders. Won't work in IE6 or IE7.
- Use the `outline` property in addition to the `border`. Outline works very similarly to border, but does have some slight differences. It can give you a third border box though, if used in addition to `border-style:double;`. Note that it might not work in older browsers.
- CSS3 `border-image`. Using this, you can define your own graphics for the border, which means you can define as many lines as you like. Note: this definitely won't work in older browsers; it's only a fairly recent addition to CSS.
- Use `background-image` to fake it. If you know the size of your box, this might be the simplest and most cross-browser compatible way to do it. Not so useful if you don't know the size of the box in advance though.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to achieve an 3d/'raised' type of border; if that's so, then you could simply use the `border-style: groove`: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RuQGU/1/).

However, if you're able, you could use the `::after` pseudo-element, and an `outset` border-style:

```
h2.bord {
    border-style:inset;
    border-width:8px;
    border-color:green;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative; /* in order to position the pseudo element relative to the parent */
    margin: 8px; /* to move the edges of the element from the container element in order to see the borders of the pseudo-element */
}

h2.bord::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -16px;
    left:-16px;
    right: -16px;
    bottom: -16px;
    border: 8px outset green;
}
```

​[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RuQGU/).